# .net WebApi OData + breeze => [Q] Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty)

Tags: javascript, odata, breeze

I have a .net 4.5 Web Api with OData EntitySetController

In client side I got the following js files loaded

```
jquery.min.js
q.min.js
datajs-1.1.1.min.js
breeze.debug.js
toastr.min.js
angular.js
```

when I call the following javascript

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("dataService", "OData");
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);

var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Customers");

return manager.executeQuery(query).then(success).fail(fail);

function success(data) {
  $log.info("Retrieved " + data.results.length);
  return data.results;
}

function fail(data) {
  $log.info("error " + data);
}
```

I see the following in my chrome network tab showing metadata and the json data are coming back nicely...

```
Request URL:http://localhost:49971/odata/$metadata
Status Code:200 OK, 1.8KB

Request URL:http://localhost:49971/odata/Customers
Status Code:200 OK, 3.3KB
```

BUT the success callback never fires, the fail callback gets executed. Can any one help please? All I see is

```
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:49971/odata/$metadata". datajs-1.1.1.min.js:14
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:49971/odata/Customers". datajs-1.1.1.min.js:14
[Q] Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty): 
[Error]
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
 q.js:1010
error Error: OK
```

I then need to databind these to a ng-grid, ng-form and then finally send them back to database to serverside...

Some more code and screen shot

```
breeze.EntityQuery
  .from("AddressTypes")
  .using(new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName))
  .execute()
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // never gets here very wierd
  }).fail(function(e) {
    console.log(e); // shows an error object with the AddressType Array
  });
```

I see the AddresTypes array in fail callback... 
[image]

update: I have temporarily switched to a BreezeContoller instead of EntitySetController in the backend, and commented out `breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("dataService", "OData");` And I get my array in successCb.  So I think I can infer I am running into trouble with DataJS. Really would like to stick with EntitySetController though...

Comment: Are there any other error messages? It seems strange that the error message is "OK".

Comment: Adding `.end()` after `fail()` will remove the "Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty)"

Comment: ` .then(function(data) {
     console.log(data); 
   }).fail(function(e) {
     console.log(e);
   }).end();` Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'end'

Comment: Ah sorry it's `.done()` not `.end()`

Comment: out put is now `'Should be empty: [] q.js:621'`. I do understand that output is by design from Q.js. But the fact remains the successCb never gets called and the data embeeded in the failureCb

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
As it turned out, going back to datajs 1.0.3 seemed to work.
However, doing that resulted $expand to not work (the server works, but breeze doesn't handle it the navigation properties -> regardless its multiplicity).

I must say, I am terrible looking for a **STABLE** breezejs equivalent.