# Breeze OData error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I've been trying for some time now to use breeze and OData.

My OData comes from another server, and CORS is enabled. I believe the problem is with breeze and odata because I've tested everything using breeze and web api and it worked just fine.

In chrome in network tab I see that OData is fetched properly but for some reason data isn't shown and I get this strange error:

```
[Q] Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty): 
[Error]
 q.js:891
Error: OK Logger.js:52


Here is my breeze DataService:

app.adminMuscleGroup.dataService = ( function(breeze, logger) {



    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);

    var service = new breeze.DataService({
        serviceName: "http://localhost:23758/odata/",
        hasServerMetadata: false,

    });

    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("dataService", "OData");


    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: service });

    manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);

    var dataService = {
        getAll: getAll,
    };

    return dataService;

    function getAll() {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("MuscleGroup").orderBy("Name");

        return manager.executeQuery(query);
    }
```

Here is Controller.js:

```
app.adminMuscleGroup.controller('AdminMuscleGroupCtrl', function ($scope) {

    var dataService = window.app.adminMuscleGroup.dataService;
    var logger = window.app.logger;

    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.getAllMuscleGroups = function() {
        dataService.getAll()
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);
    };

    $scope.getAllMuscleGroups();

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        $scope.items = [];
        data.results.forEach(function(item) {
            $scope.items.push(item);
        });

        $scope.$apply();

        logger.info("Fetched all Muscle Groups");
    }

    function queryFailed(error) {
        logger.error(error.message, "Query failed");
    }

})
```

Here is screenshot of Console log:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your logger.js file?

Comment: Sure, it is same as in Breeze ToDo sample

Comment: can you adjust your query and see what is returned - 
        return manager.executeQuery(query).fail(function(error) { logger.error(error.message, ''); });      - I want to see if there is an error thrown that is unhandled from the query

Comment: Now it says: Error: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined

Comment: And I've also added controller.js where I call dataService

Comment: Gotcha, you can delete the logger I just wanted to see what logging you had availabe.  Where are you handling the returned entities?  ie. where is that error getting thrown

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34776/discussion-between-pw-kad-and-hypern)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Breeze executeQuery Q promise fails CORS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397733/breeze-executequery-q-promise-fails-cors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that breeze doesn't work correctly when using regular EntitySetControllers for OData and CORS as you can see in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397733/breeze-executequery-q-promise-fails-cors) I asked here, and that to get them to work the controller should be a regular ApiController decorated with the BreezeControllerAttribute from [Breeze.WebApi](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.WebApi). It might have already been updated to work but I haven't tried it in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when I see 'should be empty' it means that the promise contained a rejection that was unhandled, some other unhandled error, or a promise was simply never returned for some reason.  Generally when I have this error I make sure to either console.log() the rejection reason or use something like the logger that you are using.  You can do this a number of ways but this should give you the reason for rejection, provided that you aren't using a synchronous query such as executeQueryLocally -

```
function getAll() {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("MuscleGroup").orderBy("Name");

    // added a promise failure handler 
    return manager.executeQuery(query).fail(queryFailed);
}
```

And add the following to your dataservice or w/e

```
function queryFailed(error) {
    var msg = 'Error retrieving data. ' + error.message;
    logger.logError(msg, error, 'Data call', true);
}
```

**Edit**

Ok, so now we know that something is going wrong when we are working with the data, lets see what is being returned -

**Edit 2**

Sounds like the issue is going to need the magical powers of Ward and Jay - Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this extra parameter "DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion" configuring enableCors.

config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion"));